# How can I correctly use Create.js within Require.js

Tags: requirejs, createjs

———————————————————————————
Trying to use requirejs with easeljs        ….   this works!

```
<head>
            <title>Trial Run</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainStyle.css">
            <script src="http://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/easeljs.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/tweenjs.min.js"></script>
            <script data-main="js/app" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
    </head>
```

———————————————————————————
When I remove the underlined code and setup the ’requirejs.config’ (below), 
    it fails with    …    ‘app.html:51 Uncaught ReferenceError: createjs is not defined’

```
requirejs.config({
        "baseUrl": "js/lib",
        "paths": {
        "app": "../app",
        "easel": "//code.createjs.com/1.0.0/easeljs.min.js",
        "tween": "//code.createjs.com/1.0.0/tweenjs.min.js"
 },
 "shim": {
            "jquery.alpha": ["jquery"],
            "jquery.beta": ["jquery"],
            "easel": {
                exports: 'createjs'
            },
            "tween": {
                deps: ["easel"],
                exports: "Tween"
            }
 }
```

});

// Load the main app module to start the app
requirejs(["app/main"]);

———————————————————————————
[Picture of File arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsSxs.png)
———————————————————————————

Comment: Syntax is wrong, this works !

requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js/lib",
    "paths": {
        "app": "../app",
        "easel": 'easeljs.min',
        "tween": 'tweenjs.min'
    },
    "shim": {
        "jquery.alpha": ["jquery"],
        "jquery.beta": ["jquery"],
        easel: {
            exports: 'createjs'
        },
        tween: {
            deps: ['easel'],
            exports: 'tween'
        }
    }
});

// Load the main app module to start the app
requirejs(["app/main"]);

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is wrong, this works !

requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js/lib",
    "paths": {
        "app": "../app",
        "easel": 'easeljs.min',
        "tween": 'tweenjs.min'
    },
    "shim": {
        "jquery.alpha": ["jquery"],
        "jquery.beta": ["jquery"],
        easel: {
            exports: 'createjs'
        },
        tween: {
            deps: ['easel'],
            exports: 'tween'
        }
    }
});

// Load the main app module to start the app
requirejs(["app/main"]);